# Automapper - Replacing IncludeMembers method

Tags: c#, automapper

I used the latest version of the Automapper library to write my code. After that, I needed to downgrade the TargetFramework platform and the version of the Automapper library. The required version of the library did not have a feature with the IncludeMembers() method.
How can I replace method IncludeMembers() in code example below? (p.s started exploring automapper recently)

Source:

```
class Person
{
    public Info info {get;set}
}

class Info
{
    public AdditionalInfo additionalInfo {get;set}
}

class AdditionalInfo
{
    //..
}
```

Dest:

```
class PersonModel
{
    public InfoModel info {get;set}
}

class InfoModel
{
    public AdditionalInfoModel additionalInfo{get;set}
}

class AdditionalInfoModel
{
    //..
}
```

Mapper

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonModel>().IncludeMembers(src => src.info)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.info, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.info));

CreateMap<Info, PersonModel>().IncludeMembers(src => src.additionalInfo);

CreateMap<AdditionalInfo, PersonModel>();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `IncludeMembers` but I assume that what it's doing is specifying a limited list of source members to be mapped. As far as I'm aware, the way you would achieve the same result in previous versions would be to specify `opt.Ignore` for each of those other members. The fact that that can be laborious is probably why `IncludeMembers` was added.

Comment: AFAIK `IncludeMembers` is used in flattening scenarios. In your sample, there is no flattening (each class has a corresponding model), so you could configure maps from all classes to their respective model and you are good to go. Am I missing something?

Comment: And what exactly is the new target? Because AM 10.1.1 supports _everything_ after .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: But if you're indeed targeting smth before 461, see [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7). `CreateMap<Source, Destination>().Flatten(s => s.Inner);`